# Collision Detection using algorithm and Rectangle.intersects (java/lwjgl)

Tags: java, algorithm, boolean, collision-detection, collision

I know this is a problem that very often occurs, but i can't seem to find the problem. I have searched everywhere!

The algorithm i have used for collision detection is this:

```
if( (ent1.getX() >= ent2.getX() && ent1.getX() <= (ent2.getX() + ent2.getWidth())) ||
       ((ent1.getX() + ent1.getWidth()) >= ent2.getX() && (ent1.getX() + ent1.getWidth()) <= (ent2.getX() + ent2.getWidth())) ){

        //Now we look at the y axis:
        if( (ent1.getY() >= ent2.getY() && ent1.getY() <= (ent2.getY() + ent2.getHeight())) ||
           ((ent1.getY() + ent1.getHeight()) >= ent2.getY() && (ent1.getY() + ent1.getHeight()) <= (ent2.getY() + ent2.getHeight())) ){
            //The sprites appear to overlap.
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This algorithm actually works and i found out what the problem was in the debugger...

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
public static boolean intersects(Rectangle rect1, Rectangle rect2) {
    double left1 = rect1.getX();
    double top1 = rect1.getY();
    double right1 = rect1.getX()+rect1.getWidth();
    double bottom1 = rect1.getY()+rect1.getHeight();
    double left2 = rect2.getX();
    double top2 = rect2.getY();
    double right2 = rect2.getX()+rect2.getWidth();
    double bottom2 = rect2.getY()+rect2.getHeight();
    return (
        left1 < right2
        && top1 < bottom2
        && right1 > left2
        && bottom1 > top2
    );
}
```

This is "border exclusive".

Comment: Are these the corner variables?? And if that is so, how do i get all the corner positions from x, y, width and height??

Comment: See the current (tested) version. Please, specify any "fail" situation.

Comment: Well, in any way of collision the player is with the wall (collider/rect2) nothing happens... As i said in the main entry for this question the algorithm I have written works when the bottom of the player collides with the bottom of the wall, but this is only in java, because when i used the code in C++ everything works fine

Comment: I am so very sorry for having wasted your time!! I agree i am truly retarded. The reason being i f***ng forgot to assign the height of the Entity's.... I checked the debugger and i saw there was no height on any of the rectangles.  Seriously I am terribly sorry for being so ignorrant... Lesson Learned